# nginx rewrite cuts of download file

Tags: nginx

Having this config

```
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_buffers 1024 1024k; fastcgi_buffer_size 1024k;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
    location ~ ^/(download)/{
        rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9-_.\/%20\w\s]+)+$ /dl.php?path=$1 break;
    }
```

this should trigger the download and put some statistics into database.
All files are cutted off after a few bytes.
If I trigged directly

```
    https://portal.stack.io/dl.php?path=/files/teams/one/cat/database.dump
```

everything works.
How the rewrite has to be configured to work?

**Update**
now checked the content of the downloaded file.
It is the php script which should server the file instead the zip file.

Comment: Do a `curl -v` and see something there and also post nginx logs and see if anything there

Comment: updated - seems to be a problem with filesize and fastcgi

Comment: make sure to `chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www_dl/`, assuming that `www-data` is the user in which php is running. Also notice you using http2, try disabling that?

Comment: chowned /var/www_dl and disabled http2. with /download/ file got 2kb with dl.php?path it has 138mb.

Comment: could the extra `/` in `/var/www_dl//files/teams/one/cat/database.dump` be causing the issue?

Comment: no check with another path without duplicated / and same behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve the issue by changing the nginx server conf like this

```
location ~ ^/(download)/{
    rewrite ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_.\/%20\w\s]+)+$ /dl.php?path=$1;
}
```

now it works